# Is URLSession secure over WfI?

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I am wondering if using URLSeassion to make HTTP calls is secure. Specifically, for example if I send out a POST call with a data task using a body of Data coming from a serialized dictionary like this [“name”:”Ken”] in Swift, will the POST call be able to be sniffed? Is the POST going out in a way you can just use Charles for example and read it back?

I thought that using HTTPS would prevent that, but I am not sure how to properly think about this.

Comment: HTTP is totally sniffable. That is _why_ there is HTTPS.

Comment: Ok, so if I use HTTPS the data can not be “understood”... it’s encrypted during transmission?

Comment: Read the link. That's what it's for...

Comment: With SSL the encryption is at the transport level, so it takes place before a request is sent. HTTPS (HTTP over SSL) sends all HTTP content over a SSL tunel, so HTTP content and headers are encrypted as well. Everything in the HTTPS message is encrypted, including the headers, and the request/response load.

Comment: I guess I should have looked into HTTPS before asking this question. I was mainly worried about what URLSession did or didn’t do...

Comment: URLSession doesn't "do" anything. It's no different from curl or a browser. It just talks over the network, however you tell it.